# How to get date range from week number in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to get date range from week number in sql.
eg .

```
 select datepart(week,GETDATE()) // 37
```

I want to get dates from week 37(4/09/2016 , 05/09/2016 , 06/09/2016 , 07/09/2016 , 08/09/2016 , 09/09/2016 , 10/09/2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  , @EndDate DATE = dateadd(day, 7-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) as CurrentWeekDates
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
          FROM      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```